# Tensorflow NMT with Attention Tutorial -- need help understanding loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following Tensorflow's Neural Machine Translation with Attention tutorial ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.11/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/nmt_with_attention/nmt_with_attention.ipynb)) but am unclear about some implementation details. It'd be great if someone could help clarify or refer me to a source/better place to ask:

1) `def loss_function(real, pred)`: This function computes loss at a specific time step (say `t`), averaged over the entire the batch. Examples whose labels at `t` is `<pad>` (i.e. no real data, only padded so that all example sequences are of same length) are masked so as not to count towards loss.

**My question**: It seems loss should get smaller the bigger `t` is (since more examples are `<pad>` the further we get to maximum length). So why is loss averaged over the entire batch, and not just over the number of valid (non-`<pad>`) examples? (This is analogous to using `tf.losses.Reduction.SUM_BY_NONZERO_WEIGHTS` instead of `tf.losses.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE`)

2) `for epoch in range(EPOCHS)` ——> Two loss variables are defined in the training loop:

- `loss` = sum of `loss_function()` outputs over all time steps
- `batch_loss` = `loss` divided by number of time steps

**My question**: Why are gradients computed w.r.t. `loss` and not `batch_loss`? Shouldn't `batch_loss` be the average loss over all time steps and the entire batch?

Many thanks!

Comment: It seems to me you are correct and that it's more appropriate to calculate the loss the way you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems loss should get smaller the bigger t

The loss does get smaller since the pad token is getting masked while calculating the loss.

**Batch_loss is used only to print the loss calculated of each batch.** Batch loss is calculated for every batch and across all the time steps.

```
for t in range(1, targ.shape[1])
```

This loop runs over the batch for all timesteps and calculates the loss by masking the padded values.

I hope this clears it up :)